# How to show text temporarily on an image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to show the pixel value,  while hovering the mouse, But when I use `putText` method on an image, it replaces the original image variable.

Also, I want to show the coordinates temporarily while hovering the mouse.

So, when I move the mouse to a different position, I should be able to show the current coordinates only.

Can someone please help me?

```py
# importing the libraries
import cv2

# storing the coordinates
points = []

# event function
def click_event(event, x, y, flag, params):

    global points

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 2, (0,0,0), -1)
        points.append((x,y))

        if len(points) == 2:
            cv2.line(img, points[0], points[1], (0,0,0), 2)
            points = []

        cv2.imshow('Scientists', img)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        coordinates = '('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')'
        cv2.putText(img, coordinates, (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,0))
        cv2.imshow('Scientists', img)

# reading the image
img = cv2.imread('scientists.jpg', -1)

# displaying the image
cv2.imshow('Scientists', img)

# event listener method
cv2.setMouseCallback('Scientists', click_event)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: don't draw on `img`. Inside the MOUSEMOVE event first copy img, and then draw on the copy. If you have a Qt backend for OpenCV, the window already show the pixel value

Comment: You could just keep the original image, check when the mouse is at the edge of the window, replace image with original. The opencv gui interface is not advanced. It is meant for simple debugging purposes. Anything advanced requires other gui tools like Qt.

Comment: But I already have 2 events to check for. If I draw an image inside the event, the other event will get affected as this image is local.
Can you please share the instructions to get Qt on windows?